# Not skipping by Mincha?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, mincha-afternoon-prayer, arriving-late

According to some *poskim* (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64251/on-what-authority-do-lubavitchers-not-skip-when-late-to-shacharis#comment176986_64251)), one should not skip parts of *davening* to say *Shemoneh Esreh* with the *minyan*, rather he should *daven* in order (this is unlike the ruling given in *Shulchan Aruch* (OC 52)).

According to this opinion, does the same apply to *Mincha*? If one were to [come late to *Mincha*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2762/9643), should he say everything in order (possibly including *Korbanot*)?

Comment: Korbanot are usually said privately and I don't think they would be considered part of the tzibbur Mincha. So, I think that can be said out of order. That leaves just *Ashrei*. I think most people can say this quickly enough and still be able to join the tzibur in Amidah.

Comment: Opinion - you linked to an unsourced answer. Not that a letter from the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l isn't valuable, but, if we all had a link to that source, we may be able to see if the Rebbe's answer includes info about Mincha. With your question, here, relying on that unsourced answer, it seems weak. How do we know that that the answerer relayed that info correctly?

Comment: @DanF "Korbanot are usually said privately and I don't think they would be considered part of the tzibbur Mincha" I've never heard of tzibbur mincha vs. another type of mincha. Korbanot are a part of the order of prayer. || "you linked to an unsourced answer" I linked to a [*sourced comment*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64251/on-what-authority-do-lubavitchers-not-skip-when-late-to-shacharis#comment176986_64251).

Comment: In Kabbalistic thought, Korbanot come after Mincha anyway. Since the opinion that says you can't skip is also of Kabbalistic origin, probably you have a 'mima nafshakh' of sorts that you can skip it before.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's interesting could you provide a source for where you saw that al pi kabala that korbanot come after mincha? thanks

Comment: @dude all the achronim on the shulchan aruch there quote the zohar youll see it

Comment: Sorry about the link assumption. I must have scrolled. Re the "tzibbur mincha" idea, it's similar to the additional prayers that people say after Shacharit, such as parshat hamahn, 6 *zechirot*, etc. That's my understanding of the *Korbanot* at Mincha. I may be wrong about that, but, I have to hunt the source of where I saw this a while ago.

Comment: @danf also Ani Maamin, Alenu, Shir Shel Yom, Ledavid, etc. There lots of extra things people say after prayers.

Comment: @DoubleAA Aleinu and Shir Shel Yom have an origin of having been said after Tefilla, which lead to the debate of where *Kaddish Yatom* should be said. I think today, most nuscha'ot would consider these two part of Shacharit, per se.

Comment: @DanF Maybe most people think of them that way because they are more popular than Ani Maamin, but their formal status hasn't changed. For the Halakhot of skipping, there's prayer and then there's extra stuff.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a bit cynical, but when the Aruch Hashulchan brings down that one should skip Ashrei and Korbanos in order to Daven Minchah with the Tzibur, I feel like his wording is a bit more 'extreme' than usual (i.e. throwing out the Ikar for the Tafel, calling people who do so smpletons), which makes me think that there likely were a significant group of people who were missing Tefilla Betzibur due to Korbanos.